# Array of strings concatenating positions

Tags: arrays, c, string, for-loop

I am programming a registration system using array strings for postal code and home address. I use a constant to determine the postal code limit of just 8 characters.
When the program start the register function, it makes the address and postal code inputs correct, but when I list it, the address appears normal and the postal code of position 1 together with the others below. Why is this happening? I put 8 character positions for the postal code and it increases by placing the second one as well.

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT_POSTAL 8
#define LIMIT_REGISTER 5
#define LIMIT_ADDRESS 20

char postal_c[LIMIT_REGISTER][LIMIT_POSTAL], address[LIMIT_REGISTER][LIMIT_ADDRESS];
int line;

void reg()
{
        int op;
        do
        {
                printf("Address: ");
                scanf("%s", &address[line]);
                printf("Postal code: ");
                scanf("%s", &postal_c[line]);
                op = -1;
                printf("1 - Continue\nAny number - Exit\n");
                scanf("%d", &op);
                line++;
        } while(op == 1);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    reg();
    for(i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        printf("Address: %s\n", address[i]);
        printf("Postal: %s\n", postal_c[i]);
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address: foo
Postal code: 11111111
1 - Continue
Any number - Exit
1
Address: foo2
Postal code: 22222222
1 - Continue
Any number - Exit
0
Address: foo
Postal: 1111111122222222
Address: foo2
Postal: 22222222
```

Comment: You're invoking undefined behavior by overrunning `postal_c[line]` buffer. This is only 8 chars long, input of `11111111` is also 8 chars long, but `scanf("%s"...)` tacks on a `NUL` terminating byte, this overflows your buffer by 1. You should also remove the `&` in your `scanf` `&address[line]` and `&postal_c[line]` lines.

Comment: where is the variable 'line' initialized? and without that, it is incremented in the do-while loop

Comment: thanks for the answer @yano Now the output is: 111111112. Would that be a buffer problem?

Comment: @Siddhant the variable initializes above the reg function, to be identified by the reg and main functions

Comment: Did you make any changes? You either need to make `LIMIT_POSTAL` bigger or reduce the max number of characters you enter to 7 (you can tell `scanf` to read in up to x number of characters, but I'd have to look up what that format specifier is). In general, you can only enter `LIMIT_POSTAL - 1` characters for `postal_c[line]` without overflowing your buffer.

Comment: @yano I increased it to nine characters, removed & from scanf and allowed only 8 digits: scanf ("%8s", postal_code[line]);  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your code probably:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LIMIT_POSTAL 8
#define LIMIT_REGISTER 5
#define LIMIT_ADDRESS 20

char postal_c[LIMIT_REGISTER][LIMIT_POSTAL], address[LIMIT_REGISTER][LIMIT_ADDRESS];
int line; 

void reg()
{
        int op;
        do
        {
                printf("Address: ");
                scanf("%s", &address[line]);
                printf("Postal code: ");
                scanf("%s", &postal_c[line]);
                op = -1;
                printf("1 - Continue\nAny number - Exit\n");
                scanf("%d", &op);
                line++;
        } while(op == 1);
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    reg();
    for(i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        printf("Address: %s\n", address[i]);
        printf("Postal: %s\n", postal_c[i]);
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

I can't see you had initialized `line` variable in you program and you are using it directly to pointing the index, hence you didn't assigned any value so probably it contains garbage value and pointing invalid memory address in your program.
I am assuming your rest code is correct.

try doing...

`int line =0;`

Comment: Not working... but I think that could be a mistake on int line variable. I talked with a user comments of my post about limit to 9 characters insted 8. But a another user said about the variable line. Is there a better way to declare the variable int line?